# How to find an "empty" test in jira?

Tags: jira

How to find tests without any test details(steps).
Note, there may be a description in it.
Only thing there are no test steps...
How can I search for those tests?

Comment: Hi do you mean by test ? Because is a CMS that can add project split by tasks affect to someone on the team dev, everyone have in charge to post every step by step (module by module) during development, you can reports between the team what you do adding a status of you devs ... etc

Comment: dude, I know that we all in charge to post every step...
But in my case, I have issues with type=test that are empty. I and I want to search for all of them

Comment: Sorry igor i was thinking you was a novice on Jira. For the question it depend of Jira version you got but i never got this issue, so try to find any info on jira community, and this issue is related on https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Product-Apps-questions/How-to-enable-the-quot-test-quot-issue-type/qaq-p/455878